# UIPicker displaying ? instead of text

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I'm still new to iOS coding but am trying to get my UIPicker to display the options I want, and then be able to take the option selected and do something with it.  But rather than having the picker show my options it's just showing ? marks instead of my options.

Here's my GuardCompany.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#define COLOUR 0 

@interface GuardCompany : UIViewController

<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UIPickerView *ColourAndShadePicker;

    NSMutableArray *arrayColour;
     }


@end
```

And here's my GuardCompany.m

```
#import "GuardCompany.h"

@interface GuardCompany ()

@end

@implementation GuardCompany

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (component == COLOUR)
        return [arrayColour count];

    return 0;

}

- (NSString *)GuardCompany:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (component == COLOUR)
        return [arrayColour objectAtIndex:row];

    return 0;
}

#pragma mark - view lifecycle

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    arrayColour = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrayColour addObject:@"red"];
}

@end
```

Comment: Xcode is just the IDE, so I've fixed the tags on your question. :-)

Comment: At first glance, shouldn't `- (NSString *)GuardCompany:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component` be `- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component`

Comment: Great, glad it fixed it for you!  I've made it an answer if you want to mark the answer and complete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance this looks incorrect:

```
- (NSString *)GuardCompany:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Change it to:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```